How to do Code wrapping in quarto for the whole PDF document
I want to wrap long lines of R code but they run off the page in
Quarto PDFs.
---
title: "Example"
format:
   html:
    code-overflow: wrap
---

The YAML header above works great when the output is html. But, what
is the equivalent option for format: pdf:?
I'm using Quarto in Rstudio.

https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/4121#discussioncomment-4800510

The other option would be to define own LaTeX class and use it as template. There is {listing} package for LaTeX which has breaklines option. But probably the easiest way would be to reformat the code to avoid long verbatim lines.. You can try styler package (for R, not LaTeX).
